# google app script Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined.

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

don't know why i'm getting this error when working with a spreadsheet of google: "Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined. (line 13, file "Code")"

The code is simple, just trying to look if an array contains any of other objects:

```
function combineData(){
 var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet1 = doc.getSheetByName("Sheet7");
  var Sheet2 = doc.getSheetByName("Lista de Modelos");
  var modelos = Sheet2.getRange(1,1,Sheet2.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var titulos = Sheet1.getRange(1,8,Sheet1.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  var resultados = [];

 for (var i =0;titulos[i]!="";i++){
   for(var j=0;modelos[j]!="fin";j++){
     if(titulos[i].indexOf(modelos[j])>-1){

       resultados[i]=modelos[j];}
     if(modelos[j]="Zafira"){
       resultados[i]="no Encuentra";}
   }

}
Sheet1.getRange(1,9,Sheet1.getLastRow(),1).setValues(resultados);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one of your titulos doesn't have any value - which is a different thing from `== ""` - `undefined != ""` It is quite possible that the offending titulo is from outside the range, since you're not checking for `i < titulos.length`

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped. I had some issues with .lenght and thats why I tend to not use it. But in this case it worked! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Always glad to help.